# Broadcom BCM54194 PHY Magnetics

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, lan

I am designing an application board using a third party Ethernet Switch module.  I am unable to get the Switch module manufacturer support on the recommended magnetics to use. I can see that the Switch is using Broadcom BCM54194 as the Ethernet Transceiver but again the datasheet for that is unavailable from the Broadcom website. As I understand, there are two types of magnetics connection depending on whether the PHY drivers work on Current Mode or Voltage Mode. Anyone who has worked on Broadcom PHY can help on this?

Comment: Anyone who is officially using these devices are probably under a NDA ( non disclosure agreement). I’d suggest finding a commercial unit using these devices and see what they use.

Comment: I can get hold of a Switch module with board-to-board connectors for the PHY interface. Is there any way to figure out before designing the carrier board?